# Electron - display on-screen keyboard (windows)

Tags: windows, electron

I'm building an electron app for windows tablets for a client (surface pro).  The on-screen keyboard works wonderfully for most purposes, however I have some use cases where the user clicks "new" and I display a dialog with a default text input (such as name).

In this scenario, I'd like to just pop up the on-screen keyboard if we're in tablet mode rather than force the user to click again on the name textbox.  It seems that even if I focus the textbox, the keyboard will only appear if the user taps on the text field.

Is there anyway in electron to trigger the on-screen keyboard behavior manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something I've used is running the `Tabtip.exe` from the `BrowserWindow`.

This should work in Windows 7 and Windows 10 (using the Touch Keyboard). Although I've noticed `Tabtip` doesn't work in Windows 10 when there's no touch screen.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

function showTouchKeyboard() {
    exec('start /d "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\ink" TabTip.exe', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This will work only once (when user closes keyboard he will never be able to open it again)